# Django easy-thumbnails getting weird naming with duplicate extensions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, easy-thumbnails

I'm using easy-thumbnails, the original file is saved correctly but the thumbnails are being saved with a duplicate file extension:

```
11.jpg
11.jpg.100x100_q85.jpg
```

I would like the thumbnails to be named like this:

```
11.100x100_q85.jpg
```

My model looks like this:

```
def image_filename(instance, filename):
    folder = 'posts/image'
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    new_name = str(instance.id) + ext
    return os.path.join(folder, new_name)


class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=image_filename, null=True, blank=True)
```

Since im using Django Rest Framework I created a serializer following this post:
[Django easy-thumbnails serialize with Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162196/django-easy-thumbnails-serialize-with-django-rest-framework)

```
class ThumbnailSerializer(serializers.ImageField):
    def __init__(self, alias, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.read_only = True
        self.alias = alias

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if not value:
            return None

        url = thumbnail_url(value, self.alias)
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(url)

        return url
```

Does anyone know how I can get the correct naming on my thumbnails?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try printing `ext` and `str(instance.id)` in `image_filename`?

Comment: @sunson1164 ext = '.jpg' and str(instance.id) = '11'

Comment: I believe dropping the concatenation of ext will work. i.e. `new_name = str(instance.id)`. If it works, I will add this as an answer.

Comment: I doesnt work, if I do that my thumbnail is named correctly '11.100x100_q85.jpg' but now my original image is named '11' without any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs of the library, [Link](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/56e745d48e248eb9aa38291b22075c2b5b83ef88/easy_thumbnails/conf.py#L198-L213). There are 4 namers available.

> ```
> Four namers are included in easy_thumbnails:
>
> ``easy_thumbnails.namers.default``
>     Descriptive filename containing the source and options like
>     ``source.jpg.100x100_q80_crop_upscale.jpg``.
>
> ``easy_thumbnails.namers.hashed``
>     Short hashed filename like ``1xedFtqllFo9.jpg``.
>
> ``easy_thumbnails.namers.alias``
>     Filename based on ``THUMBNAIL_ALIASES`` dictionary key like ``source.jpg.medium_large.jpg``.
>
> ``easy_thumbnails.namers.source_hashed``
>     Filename with source hashed, size, then options hashed like
>     ``1xedFtqllFo9_100x100_QHCa6G1l.jpg``.
> ```

Since you didn't set it, it will take the default option which will give `11.jpg.100x100_q85.jpg`.

However you have the option to create a custom namer. [Link](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/56e745d48e248eb9aa38291b22075c2b5b83ef88/easy_thumbnails/conf.py#L214-L217)

> ```
> To write a custom namer, always catch all other keyword arguments arguments
> (with \\*\\*kwargs). You have access to the following arguments:
> ``thumbnailer``, ``source_filename``, ``thumbnail_extension`` (does *not*
> include the ``'.'``), ``thumbnail_options``, ``prepared_options``.
> ```

Also here [Link](https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/settings/?highlight=namer#easy_thumbnails.conf.Settings.THUMBNAIL_NAMER)

Note: Someone also opened an issue at Github. [Link](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/566)